# Convert string in textbox to int

Tags: c#, string, integer

I have pass text from datagridview to textbox like this;

```
convictions.label2.Text = this.dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

**and then update the data like this ;**

```
void UPDATEConviction(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e, string f, string g, string h)
{
using (SqlConnection conn = getc())
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Conviction set Date_Convicted =@a, Court_File=@b, Police_File=@c, Station=@d,Offence=@e,Sentence=@f,Convict_Status=@g Where Serial_no = @h", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", b);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", d);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", e);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", f);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", g);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", SqlDbType.Int);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dataGridView3.DataSource = GetConvictoin();
}  
}
```

how do i convert h into interger so the data is updated

I have tried searching for a method but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h", Convert.ToInt32(h));
```

Comment: Use TryParse to avoid exceptions.

Comment: `int.TryParse(h, out var value) ? value : defaultValue`